# PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False gives error 400 on one computer but runs without error on another

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a macro which helps users set and clear filters on a PivotTable. The macro has been working fine with my whole office for months. Then for seemingly no reason, one persons computer started getting error 400 on the line:
`MySheet.MyPivotTable.MyPivotField.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False`

For reference, the actual line is `pf_New.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False` where `pf_New` is a PivotField Object defined as `Me.PivotTables("Usage").PivotFields(Sheet1.[UsedOn6].Column - 6 + new_machine)` where `new_machine` is an integer argument of the sub.

There are certainly blank items in the table's source data for that field. The line works on my computer and I can confirm that it is removing blank items from the table. But when I move to my co-workers computer and run the line, it gives error 400.

Does anyone have any ideas behind the cause, or suggestions on how to avoid the error? Is there an alternate method to filtering blank rows from this pivotfield?

Comment: You can't hide *all* pivotitems, so is it the last visible item when you try to hide it?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes! Sometimes the combination of the different filters in different fields remove all visible items from the table, but no single filter removes all items by itself. Is that a problem?

Comment: You need to make sure you're not trying to hide it if it's the only one visible - someone might have a suggestion if you can show more of the relevant code to add some context around what you're doing.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did some diagnostic tests using that PC today and discovered that their Excel had been skipping the Workbook_Open event, which means the `.RefreshAll` line never ran for them. The table, which doesn't cache the source data was essentially trying to filter a blank cache and causing an error. which makes sense given what you said about not being allowed to have no items after filtering.

Comment: @TimWilliams Now I just have to figure out why their excel is able to skip the Workbook_Open event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more investigating on the PC causing problems, I found that the cause of the error was a combination of other settings and code that failed to set up the table properly for filtering.

In the pivot table options, "Save source data with file" was unchecked and "Refresh data when opening the file" was unchecked. This was to cut down on file size and reduce the delay when opening the file.

But having those two options off means that the pivot table has no data when opening the file. Interacting with the table in Excel will display the error "The PivotTable report was saved without the underlying data. Use the Refresh Data command to update the report" but when interacting with it in VBA you instead get the error "Out of Memory" or "400".

To avoid this issue, use `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` or `YourPivotTable.RefreshTable` before attempting to apply or change any filters.

In my file, the reason why it happened to only one person and not the rest of my co-workers was because my `Workbook_Open` event does have the line `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` after a bunch of other processes. For an unknown reason that I am still investigating, this one person's PC was skipping that line.

Answer (score 1):

My post doesn't answer the original question, but could be useful to others to understand the origin of the issue: in my case the code
`PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False/True` failed with error 400
only when there was no blank items in the Pivot Table.

I solved this simply using the line of code only when I was sure that there was at least one blank item in my table. In other pivot tables where there was item zero but no blank item, simply I skipped the statement.